# Описание метки вылезает за рамки блока

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, метки, дизайн

1. Находим [метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=tags) в профиле участника
2. Наводим курсор на метку
3. Должно появится всплывающее окно с подсказкой и описанием метки

Как можем увидеть на предоставленном ниже скриншоте:
Описание метки не переносится на следующую строку и выходит далеко за рамки родительского блока

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed now.

I introduced this bug yesterday while adding keyboard navigation support to the tag popover as part of our [accessibility initiative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419586/announcing-design-accessibility-updates-on-so).